# Data retrieved from parse and use it in a viewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

this how i am retrieving user info using the `objectId` :

```
func loadData() {

    userId = toPass

    data.removeAllObjects()

    var profileQuery:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
        profileQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: userId)
        profileQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(userId, block: { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.data.addObject(objects!)
                println(self.data)  //...shouldn't be empty here
            } else {
                println("Error retrieving user: \(error) ")   
            }  
        })
   }


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadData()
   fullName.text = self.data["fullName"] as! String! // ***** error here.. cannot assign a value of type 'String' to a value of type 'String?'

}
```

error is in viewDidLoad.. Any idea where am i wrong? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

data is an array of parseobjects and you want to read parseobject property from it ... iterate through array or get specific index number from it and then load "fullname" property from it or use getFirstObject... method

Comment: how can i do that? i am a beginner here.